# Why is the QPushbuttons not interacting with the Slot function

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qt-signals

Im trying to create an tic tac toe game, where buttons are used for the positions of where the knaughts and crosses are to be used. When I move the buttons into their respective places, the slot is not triggered and nothing happens.

`

```
#include "tic_tac_toe.h"
#include <iostream>

tic_tac_toe::tic_tac_toe(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(900,900);


    initBoard();
    //showBoard();

    connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(buttonpressed()));

}

tic_tac_toe::~tic_tac_toe()
{
}

void tic_tac_toe::initBoard()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        button = new QPushButton(this);
        board.append(button);
        button->show();
        button->setFixedSize(300,300);
        //button->setStyleSheet("border: 5px solid black");
        button->setText("??");
//        button->move(x,y);
//        x = x + 300;
//        if(x == 900)
//        {
//            y = y + 300;
//            x = 0;
//        }

    }
}
void tic_tac_toe::showBoard()
{

}

void tic_tac_toe::buttonpressed()
{
    button->setText("X");
}
```

I tried doing it with only one QPushbutton and it works, however when I move and create more buttons, the Slot function does not work on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You only ever `connect` to the last `QPushButton` instance created.  Move the `connect` call from the constructor into `tic_tac_toe::initBoard` and use a lambda to capture the value of `button`...

```
void tic_tac_toe::initBoard()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        button = new QPushButton(this);
        board.append(button);
        button->show();
        button->setFixedSize(300,300);
        button->setText("??");
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this,
                [this, button]
                {
                    buttonpressed(button);
                });
    }
}
```

Likewise, update the signature of `tic_tac_toe::buttonpressed`...

```
void tic_tac_toe::buttonpressed (QPushButton *button)
{
    button->setText("X");
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing that, but the exact same issue is occuring. What is the general lack of knowledge that im missing with this problem?

Comment: In the `buttonpress` slot, `button` will also be the last added button. You could use `static_cast<QButton*>(sender())->setText("X");` to change the text of the pressed button (`sender()` will return the `QObject` that emitted the current signal)

Comment: @king_nak Thank you very much. That fixed the issue for me. If I want to learn more about the solution you provided, what would you recommend for me to search?

Comment: @king_nak Thanks, my bad.  Edited/updated accordingly.

Comment: @G.M. what would you recommend I do research on and improve my knowledge to avoid a similar situation from happening again?

Comment: That's difficult to tell, as it is general SW engineering/programming experience. I think you have to understand better the difference between objects and variables: you create 9 buttons, but have only 1 variable for them (this is not generally wrong, and ok in this place). Just try to understand which object the pointer is pointing to when, and that you lose all other buttons when reassing it. But you put it as a member variable. Why? To silence a compiler error (I'm guessing)? Better understand why the compiler complains, and what you want to do. Work with the compiler, not against it.